# Bluetooth UUID for car handsfree devices

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Can anyone help me with the UUID for car handsfree peripheral connections, so I can call scanForPeripherals withServices: [SOME UUID] instead of nil, and only return handsfree. Is there a UUID or CBUUID for this? I hope this can be done at a service level and does not need to look at characteristics. Thanks in advance if you can help me.

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

    if central.state == .poweredOn {
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [UUID HERE] , options: nil)
    } else {
        print("central not powered on")
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    print("peripheral discovered")
    peripheralLabel.text = peripheral.name
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handsfree devices implement the Bluetooth Hands Free Protocol (HFP). This is not a Bluetooth Low Energy GATT service and so does not have a service UUID. They cannot be discovered using Core Bluetooth.